# How to make an array become subarray?

Tags: php, arrays

I am working with an array which I already get the answer but I need to put 1 more array layer for my array. Below is my example :

this is my array :

```
$newOptions = array();
    foreach ($community_comment as $option) {
        $date = $option['date'];
        $text = $option['text'];

        $newOptions[$date][] = $text;
    }
```

and this is my result:

```
Array
(
    [2014-05-14] => Array
        (
            [0] => test test test test
            [1] => test2
        )

)
```

but I want my result to be like this :

```
Array
    (
       [0]=>Array(
            [2014-05-14] => Array
            (
                [0] => test test test test
                [1] => test2
            )
    )
    )
```

Hope I can get some help. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Just add `$newOptions = array($newOptions, )`.

Comment: try $newOptions[][$date][]

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you:

```
$newOptions = array();
foreach ($community_comment as $option) {
    $date = $option['date'];
    $text = $option['text'];

    $newOptions[][$date][] = $text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change
`$newOptions[$date][] = $text;`
to
`$newOptions[][$date][] = $text;`

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 0;
$fake_array = array();
foreach ($community_comment as $option) {
    $date = $option['date'];
    $text = $option['text'];

    if(isset($fake_array[$date])) {
        $newOptions[$fake_array[$date]][$date][] = $text; // $fake_array[$date] = old index
    }
    else {
         $newOptions[$i][$date][] = $text;
         $fake_array[$date] = $i;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$newOptions = array();
    foreach ($community_comment as $option) {
        $date = $option['date'];
        $text = $option['text'];

        $newOptions[][$date][] = $text;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had found out my answer and this answer is suitable to implement in my project.

```
foreach ($community_comment as $option) {
        $date = $option['date'];
        $text = $option['text'];
        $id = $option['id'];

        $data['text'] = $text;
        $data['id'] = $id;
        $newOptions[$date][] = $data;
    }

    $result = array();
    foreach ($newOptions as $key=>$value)
    {
        $result['date'] = $key;
        $result['data'] = $value;

        $result2[]=$result;
    }
```